# git difference on parameter one dash and two dashes

Tags: git, unix, parameters

in git when I specify a parameter, ie

> git log -n 5

what is the difference of using a parameter with one dash "-" as opposed to two dashes "--"

> git log --author="Larvae"

Comment: Please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/single-dashes-for-single-character-options-but-double-dashes-for-words

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's not really git specific. Many programs use the following convention:

- single-letter parameter: one dash
- multi-letter parameter: two dashes

This is handy, because it allows you to specify many single-letter parmeters at once with a single dash and all letters of the parameters you need: `ls -al` is equivalent to `ls -a -l`.

Often, one-letter parameters are the most used ones and can have a longer equivalent with two dashes: for example `git add -v` and `git add --verbose` mean the same.

Comment: useful information

Answer (score 6):

Git follows the [GNU-adjusted POSIX conventions for command line arguments](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/attributes/_posix.html). Short, one letter options start with a single dash, long options start with two.

<sup>Note that the linked page claims that this is the POSIX ("unix") standard, but that's not true. `--option` is a format pioneered by GNU.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives for commands. You may prefer using the long version to avoid a typo :).   Also the short version can be combined.  Once through the command line parser, there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding Few examples**

For single parameter use single dash

Example: **Java -v** [Here -v is single parameter]

For multi parameter use double dash

Example: **Java --version** [Here --version is multi letter parameter]