# Git commands with double dashes

Tags: git

There are some git commands that require double dashes rather than single ones.  For example

```
git reset --hard
```

Why is is that some commands require a single dash and others a double dash in git?

Comment: Double dashes are standard for long options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "git checkout <filename>" and "git checkout -- <filename>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561142/difference-between-git-checkout-filename-and-git-checkout-filename)

Comment: @random not a duplicate of ***that question***, though possibly of a different one. This question asks about the difference between short and long option flags. The question you linked to is about the double-dash that's used to separate non-path arguments from path arguments.

Comment: Probably a better match with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320511/git-difference-on-parameter-one-dash-and-two-dashes or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168989/putting-and-before-switches-in-git-commands/ @cup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options with `--` are so called "long options". They are compatible to the GNU `getopt()` function. Check the function's manual for more information about the option syntax: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html

Answer (score 2):

Quote from Wikipedia:

> In Unix-like systems, the ASCII hyphen-minus is commonly used to specify options. The character is usually followed by one or more letters. Two hyphen-minus characters ( -- ) often indicate that the remaining arguments should not be treated as options, which is useful for example if a file name itself begins with a hyphen, or if further arguments are meant for an inner command. Double hyphen-minuses are also sometimes used to prefix "long options" where more descriptive option names are used. This is a common feature of GNU software.
>   [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments)

I hope that explains it!