# Meaning of single character commands preceded by a hyphen

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

What does a hyphen followed by a single character (like `-v` `-m`, etc.) mean when working in a terminal? For example, you commit a change in the Git Bash using:

```
git commit -m "commit"
```

What are those? How are those kind of commands called? Where can I read a list of those commands for the cmd, for the Python terminal and for the Git Bash?

I've tried searching for them in google but looking for the meaning of a single character is fruitless and I don't know the correct term to look for.

Comment: Start with `git --help`

Comment: They are parameters to the command; You can find their meaning in the documentation for the command (git or python)

Comment: This is not specific to Git, nor to Python. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17320511/1256452