# Why is -f being called twice in the git command git merge --no-ff <branch-name>?

Tags: git, unix, parameters

While looking up syntax for git parameters involving one dash versus two dashes. I came across this post which explains that [single dashes allow you to specify multiple single letter parameters with one dash and double dashes are for multi-letter parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320511/git-difference-on-parameter-one-dash-and-two-dashes)

So in the case of `git merge --no-ff <branch-name>` is `-ff` calling `-f` twice? If so, why?

Comment: It's not. It's all part of one flag `--no-ff`.

Comment: Note that for this to be equivalent to `--no -f -f`, you would have had to enter `--no -ff`.  With `--no-ff` the entire string `no-ff` is the name of the option. The only special character here is `=`, which separates an option name from its value, e.g., `--cleanup=scissors` sets the `cleanup` mode to `scissors`. The space that separates arguments is handled long before `git merge` itself even gets a chance to run: `--no -ff` would be presented *to* `git merge` as two separate arguments. But the `-` (hyphen) character is not special like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in the case of `git merge --no-ff <branch-name>` is `-ff` calling `-f` twice?

No, it isn't.

`--no-ff` is the complete long option. Long options may contain dashes, because only whitespace separates command line arguments and a long option is always an entire command line argument (unlike short options, where one command line argument can contain multiple options, .i.e. `-bar` contains `b` `a` and `r`).

Answer (score 1):

`--ff` just means `fast forward`.

Semantically speaking:

- a *fast-forward merge* of a branch `other` in a current `feature` branch is a trivial merge where the SHA1 of `feature` is just "bumped" to `other` (this is not always possible, only if `other` is a child-commit-or-so of `feature`)
- a *non-fast-forward merge* of `other` in `feature` is "a true merge" which results in the creation of a new merge commit in branch `feature`, which then has two parent commits.

#### Reference

See also the online refman which indicates there are three related CLI flags:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---ff

> `--ff`
> `--no-ff`
> `--ff-only`
>
> Specifies how a merge is handled when the merged-in history is already a descendant of the current history.